# SQL Server 2017 Database Mail Silent error

Tags: windows, sql-server

I have made an installation of a development environment in VMWare that contains:

- Windows Server 2016
- SQL Server 2017

The objective is to perform migration tests of a base that is currently in:

- Windows Server 2003
- SQL Server 2008 R2
  In the old environment (2008 R2) I use Database Email to send emails without problems.

I have made the same steps to send emails in the same environment.

Everything seems to work well. The emails appear in sysmail_sentitems. No problem in sysmail_event_log.

However, the emails do not arrive.

But there is no error. Tests that I did:

- I disabled the firewall
- I disabled Windows Defender
- I connected with Telnet
- I tried different email profiles

Everything seems to go, but the mail does not arrive and there are no errors.

Any idea what I can investigate?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get anything back when you run this query?

SELECT top 100
mail.send_request_date As SentDate,
sent_status As Reason,
err.[description],
mail.*
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysmail_allitems] mail 
inner join [msdb].[dbo].[sysmail_event_log] err
ON err.mailitem_id = mail.mailitem_id
WHERE mail.sent_status <> 'sent'
order by mailitem_id desc

Comment: Nothing. All emails were sent from the point of view of SQL Server. It is as if they had been lost later.